# NHibernate Sum always rounding to integer

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a problem with sums in Linq to NHibernate (C#). I can't get the decimal parts of any totals. The field that I want to sum in my business object is C# decimal, and the mapped field in the database is DECIMAL(8,2)

The sum doesn't throw any exception, but I get only an integer (I checked with SQL in the database and the sum does have decimals).

My Fluent mapping for this field is:

```
Map(x => x.Importe).Column("importe").Nullable().CustomSqlType("DECIMAL(10,2)");
```

I tried with these expressions and the corresponding ones without the cast (decimal) and I get always the same result (sorry my business objects are in spanish, "importe" translates to "amount", and "vale" to some like "voucher" =)

```
  var total1 = (from vale in session.Query<Vale>()
                select vale).Sum(c => c.Importe);

  var total2 = (from vale in session.Query<Vale>()
                select vale.Importe).Sum();

  var total3 = (from vale in session.Query<Vale>()
                select new { vale.Importe }).Sum(c => c.Importe);
```

And casting to decimal (and decimal?):

```
  var total1 = (from vale in session.Query<Vale>()
                select vale).Sum(c => (decimal) c.Importe);

  var total2 = (from vale in session.Query<Vale>()
                select (decimal) vale.Importe).Sum();

  var total3 = (from vale in session.Query<Vale>()
                select new { vale.Importe }).Sum(c => (decimal) c.Importe);
```

The output SQL is always the same:

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(vale0_.importe) AS DECIMAL) AS col_0_0_ FROM vales vale0_
```

The problem I think is "AS DECIMAL" because I sent this SQL but with "AS DECIMAL(8,2)" and I got the correct result, but I don't know how to make NHibernate generate the correct SQL.

I tried appending .CustomSqlType("DECIMAL(10,2)") to the mapping field, and/or using .Precision(8).Scale(2) in the mapping too, but nothing.

I'm using FluentNHibernate with NHibernate 3.2.0.4000 and MySQL 5.5.19

Answer (score 2):

This might be related to [NH-2347](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2347), a bug I found in NH 3.0 and was fixed in 3.3.0.

Try upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks Diego! (Gracias Diego!) I'll try